# How can I change the term "Published" next to # of posts published on WordPress dashboard All Posts page?

Tags: wp-query

On the posts page, there are a few columns listing types of posts with their corresponding number:

All (#) Published (#) Trash (#)

How can I changed "Published" to "Saved"?

Answer (score 1):

In your theme's *functions.php* or in a plugin:

```
function prattle_custom_text( $input ) {
    if( is_admin() && 'Published' == $input ) {
        return 'Saved';
    }
    return $input;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'prattle_custom_text' );
```

It's a tid bit dirty, but it'll do the job.

Comment: You could also check the current page inside that function(so it only runs for the page it's needed for), ie. `global $pagenow;` and `if( 'index.php' == $pagenow )`..

Comment: Thank you so much for your help; trying to make this adjustment has been quite problematic. I inserted that custom code into the theme's functions.php, and the text remained unchanged. I took it out, tried inserting it into a plugin, but still got the "Published" term.